# Best place for additional functions in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel

I would like to know what is the best place to put additional functions in order to use it in a controller. Here is an example:

```
public function store(CreateServiceRequest $request)
    {

      function getMonth($value)
      {
        if ($value == 1)
          {
          return 1;
        } else
        if ($value == 2)
          {
          return 3;
        } else
            if ($value == 3)
            {
              return 6;
            } else
            return 0;
      }

      function getYear($value)
      {
        if ($value == 4)
        {
          return 1;
        } else
        if ($value == 5)
        {
          return 2;
        } else
        if ($value == 6)
        {
          return 3;
        } else
        return 0;
      }

      function getTax($price, $vat)
      {
        $tax = ($vat/100*$price);
        return $tax;
      }

      $input = Request::all();

      $months = getMonth($input['period']);
      $years = getYear($input['period']);
      $tax = getTax($input['price_net'], $input['vat']);

      $input['price_vat'] = $tax;
      $input['price_gross'] = $input['price_net'] + $tax;
      $input['period_end'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $input['period_start'])->addYears($years)->addMonths($months)->toDateString();

      return $input;
    }
```

As you can see inside the store method I wrote three functions:
getMonth, getYear and getTax. The method first fetch all request, then I need to create some new variables - for instance I get the `$input['period']` and use it to make `$input['period_end']`. So I don't change `$input['period']` value but create a new `$input['period_end']`. If I would only change existing variable I used mutator... So the question is where I should put the code of `getMonth, getYear and getTax` functions? It seems like a mess in store method...

Comment: Put general codes like this in Helper functions, and you can use them everywhere.
https://tutsforweb.com/creating-helpers-laravel/

Answer (score 2):

make `helpers.php` (in root, where `.env` file is).

```
if (! function_exists('helper_function')) {
    function helper_function()
    {
        return 'hello';
    }
}
```

and in your `composer.json` autoload it:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

now you are able to call your helper function everywhere in code base

Comment: It didn't work until I did php artisan clear-compiled
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize

Comment: @Madlon yea, any change that does something with auto-loading needs that command to be run. Feel free to edit my answer. Good luck!